# Replacing assets in Unity real-time but keeping the references intact

Tags: unity, asset-management

I'm looking forward to adding mod support into my game by allowing users to easily replace some assets with their own versions.

The way I want it to work - if there's, say, a certain texture in some folder in my compiled game, I replace the texture with the same name in my resources, but I keep references intact. That means that the texture will be replaced for every material using this texture. I don't want to change materials themselves to reference the new texture, mainly because I'll have to keep a list of materials for each texture, and because materials might be replaced by potential modder as well. It's also important to note that I want to give people the ability to change basically anything (but scripts). Sounds, music, textures, meshes, materials, fonts, localization files, shaders, so the list of references might be absolutely changed upside down and that is absolutely not the solution.

Comment: [0ad](https://github.com/0ad/0ad) even allows changing the AI because despite the graphics engine being written in obscure C++, the AI and whole game logic is in easily hackable JavaScript. I am looking forward to your solution. Are you gonna opensource the whole thing or keep the core closed?

Comment: Not currently fully done, but as of now I got to read external material as text, get variables from here, then change the sharedMaterial variables. Almost the same for meshes - I read mesh and change the source mesh structure. Can't seem to find any way to do it for, say, sounds, though.

Comment: You did not answer my question.

Comment: I mean, I did describe it to you. It's very specific to what I'm aiming to achieve, it's very specific to my restrictions (i.e. materials all share the same shader) and it likely won't fit any other project out of the box.